# Nav items having active class even when I change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am facing this issue with navigation. Whenever I switch the tabs, the route with `""` keeps being active all the time no matter what. I tried using router-exact css, but whenever I go in nested route then the menu nav stops having active class. I  believe this is because the path is `""`

Router:

```js
    {
        path: "",
        name: "Item1",
        component: Item
   }
```

Component

```html
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Item1' }" >Item1</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Item2' }" >Item2</router-link>
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'Item3' }" >Item3</router-link>
```

The lighter color is active class
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMIEB.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set `path` to `'/'` and add `exact` or `exact-path` to links: `<router-link exact :to="{...}">`

Here is the official documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact

Comment: still can't get it to work, I think the problem is here. https://i.imgur.com/S73wMHs.png https://i.imgur.com/UAX9Tkp.png, no clue why the `"/"` keeps having active class :/